# Not able to go to the function definition with SFRA code in vs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, demandware

I am not able to go to the function definition while working with SFRA in vs code by any means (i.e Ctrl+Click, F12, Right Click --> Go to Definition ), In spite of having a definition it is showing as 'No definition found'.

Can anyone please help me here, I have also noticed that the suggestion coming from vs code is not having the functions or variable I created, I am working on demandware( SFRA ).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you install [prophet debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqrTT.prophet). Once you set it up, add your cartridge path to your dw.json file. This will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. For easier future reference, it should look like this:
`"cartridgesPath": "cartridgeA:cartridgeB"`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one setting in VS code, Go to Setting and search for "Definition Link Opens In Peek" and tikmark the checkbox.
[image: See this screenshot.]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33077818)